# SSIS package variable configuration

Tags: sql, oracle, ssis, config, configuration-files

I have an SSIS package that runs daily and executes a query at an Oracle database. This query is executed only for the newly added records like:

```
select t1.* 
from info_table t1,
     dates_table t2 
where t1.date = (select t2.date from dates_table where (select max(id) from dates_table))
```

Sometimes it is needed to execute the same package for a previous date and for now I need to maintain 2 packages. 
The first ones takes the date from the query while the second one directly through a config file. 
Is there any way (maybe by creating a more complex config file) to execute the same package depending on my needs?

Many thanks

Comment: Remove dates_table from the FROM list.

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax! Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: I agree with @jarlh the query should be `SELECT * FROM info_table WHERE date = (select date from dates_table where (select max(id) from dates_table))`

Comment: Why not using Project Parameters to achieve that. And define a parameterized SQL command in the OLEDB Source: `SELECT * FROM info_table WHERE date = ?`

Comment: Dear, @jarlh thank you for your tip. The query is totally dummy. Ofcourse it is not used like this in the project.

Comment: Dear @Yahfoufi You mean by adding the 'select max date' query inside the config file and adding it through a parameter at an ole db command?

Comment: @Avlio just add a configuration to your package or a package wide variable and have it set as a boolean flag (e.g. 0 vs 1) to run normally or for a prev. day. Based on the flag construct the date in the past or present. Or use the Precedence Constraints to direct the flow one route or another.

Comment: Can you provide the dates_table's table meta data?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way (maybe by creating a more complex config file) to
>   execute the same package depending on my needs?

Not easily. The easiest (this is relative BTW) would be to have a control table for the table for SELECTing the date from and then you just manipulate that table in such a way that the SELECT would grab for. This also requires a re-factoring of the SELECT query to abandon SELECTing MAX(DATE). If you need dates table to store historical dates then you will need to add another column that acts like a switch for indicating which date to load for and then order by DATE ascending. For example:

```
ID         DateLoadInd
3/21/2019  1 -- this will load
3/20/2019  0 -- this will not load
3/19/2019  0 -- this will not load
3/18/2019  0 -- this will not load
3/17/2019  1 -- this will load 

SELECT T1.*
FROM Info_Table T1
INNER JOIN Date_Table T2
ON T1.Date = T2.ID
WHERE T2.DateLoadInd = 1
ORDER BY T2.ID ASC
```

Alternatively, you can abandon joining to the Date_Table and just parameterize the query to receive the value through a package parameter that is mapped to a variable. I do not like this approach because it requires the SQL Server to determine and feed the date to job. I do not think it is possible to use a GETDATE() function in a package parameter in the hopes that it will be executed to determine a date (i.e., it is passed as a string only). So, you cnanot take the approach of allowing the job to run automatically in the hopes that you can just let it run for the current date unless you want to override and provide a specific date. Even if that did work, you would still need to remember to flip the package parameter back to GETDATE() - it is more work than it is worth and that is why I do not like it vis-a-vis creating a more complex config file.

On that note, when you say:

> (maybe by creating a more complex config file)

I understand that to say you are using the legacy package deployment model instead of the more modern (and better IMHO) project deployment model.